# How to send data from a class to an Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I am implementing FCM(Firebase cloud messaging) for push notifications. I could get push notification from the server using my service class successfully. But, how do I send data(messages) from the service class to the activity?

**Service.java**

```
public class Service extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }


    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FCMActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri =RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new
                NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        notificationBuilder.setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**FCMActivity.java**

```
public class FCMActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fcm);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wants to send "messageBody" into my Activity.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options, among those are:

1. Register a `BroadcastReceiver` inside your Activity with an `IntentFilter` for your custom action (action is just a `String` identifier for a broadcast message type), and send the broadcast from service using `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance().sendBroadcast(Intent intent)` method
2. Use an event bus, for example the very popular [GreenRobot EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library. See https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus#eventbus-in-3-steps for explanation.

Both of these options require registering and unregistering a listener / receiver inside your Activity, which is best done in `onResume`/`onPause` for events that should trigger UI changes.

Additionally, you can [bind to the service from your Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

Comment: If you decide to use BroadcastReceiver, the best option really is to register/ unregister it in onResume() / onPause(), otherwise it can throw an “IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState”.  This will also cut down on unnecessary system overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `IBinder` in your service and `ServiceConnection` in your Activity